# Bootstrap nested column not working mobile on device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I'm designing a website but my bootstrap column grid is working properly for laptop and tablet screens. But not working fine for mobile

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 mt-2">
                                                <span class="border border-primary rounded" style="background-color:#0275d8;display:inline-block;padding:10px;"> </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                                                <h2>Who we are</h2>
                                                <hr>
                                                <p>Scaoasijdaosijdoaisdjh.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 mt-2">
                                                <span class="border border-success rounded" style="background-color:#5cb85c;display:inline-block;padding:10px;"> </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                                                <h2>What we do</h2>
                                                <hr>
                                                <p>textxtxttx</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

basically on this content, there is one column having an empty color border that behaves like bullet/numbering on the left and remaining columns having text (h2, hr, p) on the right side of the bullet. On a mobile screen, the bullet gone top of my other remaining columns.
what is the problem here that I can't resolve??

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is.I have ran it on codepen but can't see any problem in your page when in mobile view.It's the same as in desktop view

Comment: can you show me how you see that??

Comment: https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/XWmavXQ

Comment: When you reduce the browser size, there is no difference

Comment: as you see colors boxes I want that box with heading not above to the heading

Comment: That means you want to write heading inside that box.ok

Comment: Do you want something like this?https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/XWmavXQ

Comment: no @RishabhdevTyagi I edited my HTML code with bootstrap CDN run and see what basically what I want in the mobile view and normal desktop view it's fine. I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: Mobile view is same as desktop view in your page.Do you want the headings inside  when you switch to moblie view?

Comment: no man, my browser showing different. You check my above edited HTML code with Bootstrap CDN. Am I right??

Comment: No, I just want the same desktop and mobile view which is not man.

Comment: I have added an answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what you want:

codepen: https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/JjYrLEB

```css
.col-md-11, .col-sm-11, .col-xs-11{
  position:fixed!important;
  margin-left:80px;
  
}

.new1{
  margin-left:-30px;
  margin-top:-9px;
}


.row1{
  
 
   
  position:fixed; 
  display:inline;
  margin-left:500px;
  width:700px;
  
  
  
  
  
}

.row{
  
 
  
  position:fixed; 
  display:inline;
  
  width:800px;
  
  
  
}

.para{
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:40px;

}
.para1{
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:40px;
}


hr{
  width:700px;
  float:left;
 }

.border1{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-100px;

}

@media all and (max-width:768px){

.row{
position:fixed;

}
  
  .row1{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
margin-left:450px;
}
  .head{
  font-size:25px;
  
}
  hr{
  width:250px;
  margin-left:0px;
  
  
}

}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 mt-2">
       <span class="border border-primary rounded" style="background-color:#0275d8;display:inline-block;padding:10px;"> </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="new col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                                                <h2 class="head">Who we are</h2>
                                                <hr>
                                              <p class="para">Scaoasijdaosijdoaisdjh.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="row1">
                                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 mt-2">
                                                <span class="border1 border-success rounded" style="background-color:#5cb85c;display:inline-block;padding:10px;"> </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="new1 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">
                                                <h2 class="head">What we do</h2>
                                                <hr>
                                                <p class="para1">textxtxttx</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Similarly, you can use media queries for more modifications.